# TypeScript generics with no upcasting

Tags: typescript

I use lodash/fp’s sortBy function in TypeScript.

```js
import { sortBy } from "lodash/fp";

type Card = {
  num: number;
};

type ExtraCard = Card & {
  extra: string;
};

const sortByNum = sortBy<{ num: number; }>(c => c.num);

const cards = sortByNum([
  { num: 1 }, 
  { num: 2 }
]);
const extraCards = sortByNum([
  { num: 1, extra: "A" }, 
  { num: 2, extra: "B" }
]);
```

I expect typeof cards equals `Card[]` and typeof extraCards equals `ExtraCard[]`.
But both of types are equals `{ num: number; }[]`.

So, I tried to use generics in sortByNum function.

```
const sortByNum = <T extends { num: number; }>sortBy<T>(c => c.num);
```

It causes compile error…

How to prevent those upcasting?

Answer (score 1):

Be more specific to the compiler

```js
const sortByNum = sortBy<Card>(c => c.num);

const cards: Card[] = sortByNum([
  { num: 1 }, 
  { num: 2 }
]);
const extraCards: ExtraCard[] = sortByNum([
  { num: 1, extra: "A" }, 
  { num: 2, extra: "B" }
]);
```